# Reading All Files in C++ stopped by . folder

Tags: c++, windows, recursion

I would like to create a c++ project that loops through a given folder (C:, in most cases,) and provides a list of the names and/or any given attribute. I have a successful loop with FindFirstFile(), but after the first recurse, I inevitably enter a loop where my path becomes C:\$GetCurrent..... until strcpy gives up.
The code is

```
// LoopFiles.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ShellAPI.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <strsafe.h>

void FindAllFiles(LPCSTR path);

int main()
{
    FindAllFiles("C:");
    return 0;
}

void FindAllFiles(LPCSTR path) {
     LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA data = new WIN32_FIND_DATAA();
     char searchPath[MAX_PATH] = "";
     HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

     strcpy_s(searchPath, path);
     strcat_s(searchPath, "\\*");

     hFind = FindFirstFileA(searchPath, data);

     do {

        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind)
        {
             continue;
        }

         if (data->dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
            strcpy_s(searchPath, path);
            strcat_s(searchPath, "\\");
            strcat_s(searchPath, data->cFileName);
            FindAllFiles(searchPath);
         }
         else {
             std::cout << data->cFileName;
        }
    } while (FindNextFileA(hFind, data));

}
```

Obviously, this code runs on Windows. What can I do to prevent this bug from happening?

Comment: Exclude '.' (current dir) and '..' (dir above) from the loop explicitly

Comment: @Slava How do you recommend I do that, checking the name failed to find them.

Comment: @A.Rawson How did you check the names? You didn't happen to use `==`, or misuse `strcmp`?

Comment: You compare `data->cFileName` to "." and "..": for example `if( data->cFileName[0] == '.' and ( data->cFileName[1] == 0 or data->cFileName[1] == '.' ) ) continue;`

Comment: @molbdnilo I used !strcmp(data->cFileName, "."), so probably misusing strcmp.

Comment: @Slava That worked, I actually didn't know that you could use [0] on cFileName.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Sorry, I did use not on it.

Comment: @Slava Oh, never mind. I use C# normally, forgot about char arrays. That should work. Can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude directories with names "." (current directory) and ".." (parent directory) from the search, possible solution:

```
if( data->cFileName[0] == '.' and ( data->cFileName[1] == 0 or 
        ( data->cFileName[1] == '.'  and data->cFileName[2] == 0 ) ) )
    continue;
```